Introducing a New Geometric Approach to the Pythagorean Theorem—Seeking Your Insights!
I've been exploring geometric transformations and thought I'd share a new approach I've been working on for proving the Pythagorean theorem. I'm excited to hear your thoughts and get some feedback!

The Pythagorean Theorem Recap:
In any right-angled triangle, the sum of the squares of the two shorter sides equals the square of the hypotenuse:

My Geometric Proof Attempt:

Construct a Right-Angled Triangle:

Start with a right-angled triangle , where angle  is 90 degrees.
Let the sides be:
Hypotenuse

Build an Adjacent Rectangle:

Construct rectangle  adjacent to side  with dimensions .

Apply a Shearing Transformation:

Shear rectangle  along side  to form a parallelogram  without changing its area.
The top side of the rectangle shifts horizontally by length , creating parallelogram  with sides  and .

Dissect the Parallelogram:

Draw a perpendicular from the shifted top corner of  down to side , splitting  into:
A rectangle  with dimensions .
A right-angled triangle congruent to .

Analyze the Areas:

Area of rectangle : .
Area of parallelogram :  (since shearing preserves area).
Area of rectangle : .
Area of triangle : .

Attempt to Establish the Relationship:

Since  consists of  and :
Simplifying:
Here's where I hit a snag. The simplification leads to , which doesn't hold true unless , which isn't generally the case.

Seeking Your Expertise:
I'm reaching out to see if anyone can help identify where my reasoning might have gone astray or how this approach might be adjusted to correctly prove the theorem.
Questions:
Has anyone seen a similar method or can point out where I might have erred?
Is there a way to modify this construction to make it valid?
Could this approach lead to a valid proof with some adjustments?

Why This Could Be Exciting:
Fresh Perspective: Exploring new geometric proofs can deepen our understanding and appreciation of fundamental theorems.
Collaborative Discovery: Your insights could help refine this approach or inspire new ones.

Looking Forward to Your Thoughts!
I'm excited to discuss this with you all and see where we can take this idea together. Thanks for reading, and I appreciate any feedback you might have!
Edit: After some reflection, I realized that my area calculations might be off, and perhaps the construction needs tweaking. Any suggestions are welcome!

Your proof is somehow rather wordy at the same time that it's quite difficult to follow. There are dozens of proofs from all over the world and across centuries of this ancient theorem. Here's an animation of a proof by shearing that is perhaps similar to what you have in mind?
